# Values inside a custom field to determine which category posts to display

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type

I am facing a little problem whilst trying to display posts, from certain categories, on the front end. I've created a custom field whose key is 'related_categories' and I've different categories with slugs such as 'army', 'navy', 'airforce' etc.

When creating a new custom post, I enter the slugs of different categories inside the 'related_categories' custom field, for e.g. 'navy', 'airforce', and this is the code which I've inside my template file to echo the custom field values inside the 'tax_query' array.

```
<?php global $post;

$related = array ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_categories', true) );

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'medals', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'medal-categories', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $related, ), ), ) ); 

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

//loop starts after this
```

Now the problem which I am facing is that if I enter only one slug inside the 'related_categories' custom field, for e.g. 'navy', then the posts from the 'navy' category successfully show up but if I enter more than one slug inside the 'related_categories' custom field, for e.g. 'navy', 'army', then the posts do not show up.

I tried searching for a solution on the internet but couldn't find any therefore any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at last! Instead of using:

```
$related = array ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_categories', true) );
```

I was advised to use:

```
$related = explode(',', trim( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_categories', true) ) );
```

along with adding the category slugs inside the custom field in the following format:

```
navy, army, air-force..
```

This is how the final code looks like:

```
<?php global $post;

$related = explode(',', trim( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_categories', true) ) );

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'medals', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'medal-categories', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $related, ), ), ) ); 

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

//loop starts after this
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this plug-in. I hope all of you problems will solve in this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

In this u can easily assign which fields need to show in which category and pages.